# How to Get Rid of Unwanted Backslashes in WordPress Form Input inside admin menu option

Tags: plugin-development, scripts

I'm building a simple plugin that allows adding custom scripts to header and footer. Everything seems to work fine, but there is a 'bug'. When I add Google Analytics script to header, it shows with backslashes before apostrophes. I tried:

```
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
$_POST      = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_POST );
$_GET       = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_GET );
$_COOKIE    = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE );
$_REQUEST   = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST ); }
```

but that didn't solve the problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation page for **get_magic_quotes_gpc** you can read:

*Returns 0 if magic_quotes_gpc is off, 1 otherwise. Or always returns FALSE as of PHP 5.4.0.*

I guess this can cause the first problem (that your code not works).

Next **stripslashes_deep**

You can use code like this:

```
$_POST = stripslashes_deep( $_POST );
```

But just check the [WordPress docs for the function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep) because you can break functions of the core or other plugins that expect their values slashed.

So it is probably better to work only on your own input vars:

```
$my_value = stripslashes( $_POST['value'] );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've implemented the last thing you mentioned: $old_option_header = get_option('onixion_header_scripts');
  $temporary_option_add_header = stripslashes($_POST['header_scripts']);
  $new_option_header = $temporary_option_add_header;
  $new_option_header .= $old_option_header; 
  update_option('onixion_header_scripts',$new_option_header);